# jQuery getJSON doesnt send cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

i am including JS on domain1 form domain2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain2.com/script.js"></script>
```

that script doesn onload and on button click a JSONP request to domain2

```
$.getJSON( 'http://www.domain2.com/process?callback=?',
    function(data){
        if ( data ) processData( data );
    }
);
```

and then displaying the data on domain1.

So here is my problem:
The getJSON request doesnt send cookies to the domain2.
The weirdest thing is that it does send the cookies half a day and the other half not. :-)

This is how the request looks like when it doesnt work:

```
Request details
GET /ajax/embed-user-library?detail=98&callback=jsonp1312398534998 HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50
Host: www.floowie.com
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en,sk-SK;q=0.9,sk;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.sokker.cz/en/test2
Connection: Keep-Alive

Response details
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2011 19:06:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5-0.dotdeb.1
Set-Cookie: SESSID=64292b70dc28d7c6c9f13f70070353d8; path=/; domain=.floowie.com
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 34
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

And this when it works(nothing changed in the scripts):

```
Request details
GET /ajax/embed-user-library?detail=99&test=1&callback=jsonp1312398534999 HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50
Host: test1.floowie.com
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en,sk-SK;q=0.9,sk;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.sokker.cz/en/test2
Cookie: __utma=254918925.1489796832.1301725317.1312260335.1312298033.44; __utmz=254918925.1312298033.44.11.utmcsr=sokker.cz|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/en/test2; lang=en; FLWSESSID=ddd1bc696f83f5a70b5f0f3ae30b4691; __utma=121955676.1030804516.1282595153.1312390656.1312397285.194; __utmb=121955676.8.10.1312397285; __utmc=121955676; __utmz=121955676.1312397285.194.21.utmcsr=floowie.crmserver.cz|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/index.php
Connection: Keep-Alive

Response details
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2011 19:07:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5-0.dotdeb.1
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Did someone see such a behaviour?
Is it solvable?

Thank you

Answer (score 34):

If you want to use AJAX petitions over different domains/subdomains you have to implement Cross Origin Requests.

References:

- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Examples:

- http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/

Your server needs to send this headers:

- **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: test1.floowie.com
- **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**: true // allow cookie/session credentials
- **Access-Control-Allow-Methods**: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

You can return the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** globally or set specifically dependent of your input **Origin** ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) request header. Also apply for **Access-Control-Allow-Methods**.

You **must** implement the **OPTIONS** petition. Before the first AJAX call, modern browsers call that URL with an OPTIONS method to retrieve the above headers.

Ok this is the first part, the second is with jQuery. Read very carefully this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You will need to add some options to every AJAX call, you can do it globally:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    settings.xhrFields = {
        withCredentials: true
    };
});
```

Or specific:

```
$.ajax({
    url: a_cross_domain_url,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

This issue made ​​me lose **many** hours... hope it helps.

Note that you won't need to set your cookie domain as ".floowie.com" if you want.

Comment: about this problem this is the best solution/explanation i found on the internet! also remember to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a specific domain instead of "*" or you will get this error: "Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true."

Comment: Thanks! So, it's not possible to use CORS with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" ? What about using a webapp using local HTMLs and connecting to API, you need to specify the wildcard... :S Are you sure?

Comment: just had to deal with this myself. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" is not possible for credentialed requests only - see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control). Requests without credentials are ok with *.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is **not** _always_ required to make an OPTIONS petition (pre-flighted request is the technical term) before sending the actual request. The documentation at developer.mozilla.org clearly states: "a request is preflighted if: It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST. Or It sets custom headers in the request." If your request is simply using GET, you do not need to pre-flight.

Answer (score 1):

You must properly implement CORS requests with credentials to send and receive cookies via Ajax. See [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), specifically under the section titled "Requests with credentials."

First off, here is a simple CORS Ajax request with credentials, using jQuery 1.5.1+:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.domain2.com/process",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
}).done(function (data) { console.log(data); });
```

Note the `withCredentials` flag in the xhrFields. This flag tells the browser to send cookies with the request for the *external* domain, not the *origin* domain. In your case, cookies for *www.domain2.com* will be sent, and you will have access to them server-side.

On the server-side, you need to add certain headers to the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.domain1.com
```

**Important:** requests with credentials cannot set the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header to global (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). It must specify domains (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.domain1.com`).

It's obviously better if you specify a domain for the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header. But if you don't know or care where the CORS request is coming from, you could use the `Origin` header from the request and simply set the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header of your response to that. In C#, this is how we did this:

```
this.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", this.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
```

After doing all of this, cookies that you set server-side will be sent back with the response, and the browser will be able to properly handle them and insert them into the browser's cookie store for *www.domain2.com*. And any subsequent CORS requests you send will send these cookies in the request as well.

If you are sending a request other than with the GET, POST, or HEAD methods, you will need to implement [**Preflighted requests**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (see under section titled "Preflighted requests"):

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send.  Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data.  In particular, a request is preflighted if:
>
> - It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
> - It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)

**Side-note about IE8 and IE9:**
The Ajax call above will fail in IE8 and 9. I included the JS file from [MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) on my page, and this automagically allowed CORS requests to work in those old IE versions. But sadly, the XDomainRequest object that MS created for IE8 and 9 does not allow cookies to be sent or received. (see [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) for more information)

Answer (score -1):

You have different hosts. In the first example the host is "Host: www.floowie.com". In the second it is "Host: test1.floowie.com".

I'm guessing that the cookies are originally set by 'test1.floowie.com' and you haven't specified that they should be available to '.floowie.com' (i.e. the whole domain and all subdomains).

Can you post the code that sets the cookies in the first place?

If you get this fixed, it should at least show consistent behaviour. However, IE will probably still not pass cookies across subdomains. That's what I'm wrestling with at the moment, which is how I can across your question.